# How to extend WCF DataServices and EntityFramework Model using MEF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, mef, wcf-data-services

I'm using a vanilla WCF DataService class exposing a simple Entity Framework Model. The service is contained in a simple Web Application published to IIS. Nothing fancy, right!

I'm trying to build what MSDN describes this way

> **Request and Application Scope**
>   Instances of parts created in an MVC app
>   exist in one of two scopes: the request scope or the application
>   scope. By default, part instances that are created during a web
>   request are in a request scope. Instances of parts that are in the
>   same request are shared, so if more than one part imports a given
>   part, all importers receive a reference to the same instance. Each web
>   request has its own scope, so parts created in one request are never
>   used to fill imports in another request. When a request ends, its
>   associated scope is destroyed and any parts created for it are
>   destroyed. Parts that implement an IDisposable object are disposed.
>   This ensures that sensitive resources, such as database connections,
>   are properly closed. Sometimes, you might not want to create a part
>   instance for each request (for example, when you implement an app-wide
>   cache). In these cases, you can force a part to be created in the
>   application scope by applying the ApplicationScoped attribute. Parts
>   in the application scope are always shared by all requests in the app.
>   A part in the application scope may depend on other part in the
>   application scope only for its imports. Parts in the application scope
>   must be careful to be thread-safe.

One of the main problems is that I don't know where to create the RequestScope Container. I think the RequestScope Container should be build outside of the DataService class, right?

Any help appredicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you need something similar, I've got a working solution which I've post here

```
public class MefDataServiceHostFactory : DataServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(
            Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new MefServiceBehavior());
            return host;
        }
    }

    public class MefInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
    {
        #region fields

        private readonly Type _serviceType;
        private IDependencyScope _diScope;

        #endregion

        #region ctor

        public MefInstanceProvider(Type serviceType)
        {
            _serviceType = serviceType;
        }

        #endregion

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
        }
```

Here comes the important section where one can use MEF or what ever IOC.

```
        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
           _diScope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope();
            return _diScope.GetService(_serviceType);
        }

        public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
        {
           if (_diScope != null) _diScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Get a new Instance and dispose the request

```
    public class MefServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
    {
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase cdb in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                var cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;
                if (cd != null)
                {
                    foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in cd.Endpoints)
                    {
                        ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new MefInstanceProvider(serviceDescription.ServiceType);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
                                         Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints,
                                         BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
        }
    }
```

Register the custom factory in your svc file

```
<%@ServiceHost Service="DataService"
               Factory="MefDataServiceHostFactory"
               language=c# Debug="true" %>
```

or add a new service route.

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(string.Empty, new MefDataServiceHostFactory(), typeof (DataService)));
```

happy coding!